# Процедуры в Delphi

Tags: delphi

Добрый день. Изучаю  Delphi по учебнику Никиты Культина (Использую Rad Studio XE7, Win7 32). Автор предлагает задачу перерасчёта скорости ветра из м\сек в км\ч. Решение он предлагает следующим образом:

```
// пересчитывает скорость
procedure WindSpeed;
var
   ms :integer;
   kmh :real;
begin
//Проверяем ввод данных
if Length(Form1.Edit1.Text) = 0 then
begin
   ShowMessage('Нужно ввести число');
   exit;
end;
ms :=StrToInt(Form1.Edit1.Text);
kmh := ms * 3.6;
Form1.Label3.Caption := FloatToStr(kmh);
end;

//Нажатие на кнопку Button
procedure Tform1.Button1Click (Sender: TObject);
begin
   windSpeed;
end;

//проверка нажатий клавиш в Edit1
procedure Tform1.Edit1KeyPress (Sender: TObject; var Key :char);
begin
case Key of
'0'..'9', #8:;
#13: windSpeed;
else Key :=chr(0);
end;
```

После компиляции получаю ошибку в Type:
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(17): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: 'TForm1.sendEnter'

Я решил проблему другим образом. Я отказался от создания собственной процедуры в пользу перенаправления после нажатия Enter процедуре Button:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
Label1.Caption := 'Добрый день. Программа переводит Скорость ветра из метров в секунду в киллометры в час.';
label2.Caption := 'Введите данные ниже: ';
Label3.Caption := 'Тут будет ваш ответ';
edit1.Text := '';
Button1.Caption := 'Посчитать.';
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
ms :integer;
mhk :real;
begin
  if Length(Form1.Edit1.Text) = 0  then
  begin
    ShowMessage ('Вы ничего не ввели. Повторите');
    exit;
  end;
  ms := StrToInt(Form1.Edit1.Text);
  mhk := ms * 3.6;
  Form1.Label3.Caption := 'В пересчёте из км\с в км\ч '+ IntToStr(ms)+ ' имеет значение:'+Floattostr(mhk);
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
   case key of
    '0'..'9', #8:;
    #13:  Button1Click(nil);
    else key := chr(0);
   end;
end;

//procedure sendEnter;

end.
```

В таком случае всё работает. В чём подвох решения задачи по учебнику?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**В первом отрывке у тебя sendEnter вообще не упоминается.**

В общем виде: процедуру нужно объявить до того, как её используешь.

Если в заголовке объявляешь процедуру, то потом в теле должна быть эта процедура написана (причем так же, иначе будет ошибка, только другая).

**Обновление**

добавляй это по образу и подобию самой дельфи. При объявлении в заголовке класса перед именем процедуры имя класса не указывается, а вот в теле что-то вроде

```
procedure TForm1.WindSpeed;
begin
end;
```

Внутри одного класса процедуры могут обращаться напрямую по имени.

Если у тебя процедура вне класса TForm1, то к переменным и функциям-процедурам нужно обращаться через объект класса (например, Form1.Label3.Caption это обращение к содержимому Label3. Доступ, к процедуре внутри TForm1 будет так Form1.WindSpeed; )

**Обновление**

Sender: TObject - это не обязательно. В Дельфях так делают для универсальности.

вызов из TForm1.Button1Click можно упростить и просто писать sendEnter(nil); (из одного и того же класса к процедурам лучше обращаться напрямую, не используя имя переменной).

Comment: procedure WindSpeed - эта процедура автора учебника. Во второй части кода это то, что писал я сам. Там я назвал ее sendEnter. Автор в учебнике явно не указывает, где и как я должен объявить свою процедуру. Поэтому я просто добавил её в Type:

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure sendEnter(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
  private
но по итогу получаю ошибку

Comment: Вы оказались правы. Я оформил код в соответствии вашей рекомендации:

    {type
     procedure sendEnter(Sender: TObject);

    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      Form1.sendEnter(nil);
    end;}

Программа начала работать.